# insertBefore() with multiple selectors class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I try to do that :

```
$("<div class='line line1'></div>").insertBefore(".anim-letters .wpb_wrapper .text-wrapper");
```

The div is insert after .anim-letters and no after .text-wrapper why ?
I'm obliged to add that with jquery because it will be so difficult to find the line in php code of wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem, but i would like to know why insertBefore() can't do same thing.

```
$(".text-wrapper").prepend("<div class='line line1'></div>");
```